# How to catch both swipe and long click events on LinearLayout and all its children views?

Tags: java, android, swipe, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I'm creating custom calendar view which is vertical LinearLayout filled with horizontal LinearLayouts which are filled with my cell views. I want the whole calendar to be swipeable and each cell to be long clickable. I found some code but it's good for normal click not long click.

```
    private class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            ShiftCalendar.this.setShownDate(MONTH_PREV, CURRENT_YEAR);
            ((ShiftCalendarActivity) getContext()).setShownDate(getShownDate());
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            ShiftCalendar.this.setShownDate(MONTH_NEXT, CURRENT_YEAR);
            ((ShiftCalendarActivity) getContext()).setShownDate(getShownDate());
        }

        public void onSwipeTop() {
        }

        public void onSwipeBottom() {
        }

        public final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                ShiftCalendar.this.onTouchEvent(e);
                return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                boolean result = false;
                try {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffX > 0) {
                                onSwipeRight();
                            } else {
                                onSwipeLeft();
                            }
                        }
                        result = true;
                    } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

 ////////////////////////////////

private OnSwipeTouchListener listener = new OnSwipeTouchListener(context);
mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(listener);
rows[.].setOnTouchListener(listener);
cells[.][..].setOnTouchListener((new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        return !listener.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                        }
                    });
```